# Как правильно переписать кусок на sass?

Tags: css, вёрстка, sass

**Вот такой кусок кода css на sass :**

```css
.no-gutter > [class*='col-']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть хороший сервис - [ссылка](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com)

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-']
  margin: 0
  //some text
```

Comment: спасибо, крутой сервис, ток пробелы лишние ставит)

Comment: .no-gutter > [class*='col-']
  padding-right: 0
  padding-left: 0

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко, не за что =)